# Get list of dates without entries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I am looking to find a solution to this problem. I have a table called LogEntry that stores information used by multiple offices, where they have to log any visitors that come in to their office on any given day. If no visitors come in, they are still required to log "No Visitors" for the day. How do I run a query that pulls all dates where an office failed to create even a "No Visitors" log?

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129649/while-loop-in-sql-server-2008-iterating-through-a-date-range-and-then-insert) (and the article linked within), but even adapting that query, I'm only able to create a blank row for a date where an office is missing an entry for a date, not specify the actual office that did not create an entry. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

```
declare @temp table (

CDate datetime,
loc_id varchar(50)
)

insert into @temp SELECT DISTINCT entryDate, locationID FROM LogEntry WHERE entryDate >= '05/01/2017' AND entryDate <= '07-31-2017' 

;with d(date) as (
  select cast('05/01/2017' as datetime)
  union all
  select date+1
  from d
  where date < '07/31/2017'
  )

select DISTINCT t.loc_id, CONVERT(date, d.date)
    FROM d LEFT OUTER JOIN @temp t ON d.date = t.CDate
    GROUP BY t.loc_id, d.date
    ORDER BY t.loc_id
```

As I said, this query returns me a list of dates in the date range, and all locations that submitted entries on that date, but I'd like to find a way to extract essentially the opposite information: if an office (specified by locationID) did not submit an entry on a given day, return only those locationIDs and the dates that they missed.

```
Sample data

EntryID | locationID | entryDate
=================================
1         1            07-01-2017
2         1            07-02-2017
3         2            07-02-2017
4         1            07-04-2017

Expected Result (for date range of 07-01 to 07-04)

locationID | missedEntryDate
============================
1            07-03-2017
2            07-01-2017
2            07-03-2017
2            07-04-2017
```

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is irrelevant, and use a `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I added the distinct because a location can create multiple entries for a given date; i'm only interested in knowing that they created at least one.

Comment: What I mean is, the `GROUP BY` will inherently make the query `DISTINCT`.

Comment: some sample data and expected result would help here

Comment: For dates you should try to use ansi format `YYYY-MM-DD` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataset is not too large you can try this:

```
select t.loc_id, CONVERT(date, d.date)
FROM d
    -- Cross join dates to all available locs
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT loc_id FROM @temp ) AS Locs
    LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT loc_id, t.CDate
        FROM @temp 
        GROUP BY loc_id, d.date ) AS t ON d.date = t.CDate AND Locs.loc_id = t.loc_id
ORDER BY Locs.loc_id
```

This should be a bit faster:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a.LocID, RangeStart.CDate, ( CASE WHEN Input.LocID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS IsMissing
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT LocID FROM #temp ) AS a
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT CONVERT( DATETIME, '2017-05-01' ) AS CDate ) AS RangeStart
    LEFT JOIN
            ( SELECT LocID, MIN( CDate ) AS CDate
            FROM #temp
            WHERE CDate = '2017-05-01'
            GROUP BY LocID ) AS Input ON a.LocID = Input.LocID AND RangeStart.CDate = Input.CDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.LocID, a.CDate + 1 AS CDate,
         ISNULL( ItExists, 0 ) AS IsMissing
    FROM cte AS a
        OUTER APPLY( SELECT LocID, 1 AS ItExists FROM #temp AS b WHERE a.LocID = b.LocID AND a.CDate + 1 = b.CDate ) AS c
    WHERE a.CDate < '2017-07-01'
)
SELECT * FROM cte OPTION( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

You can also add an index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_tmp_LocID_CDate ON #temp( LocID, CDate )
```

Sample data set for the second query:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp( LocID VARCHAR( 50 ), CDate DATETIME )
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
( '1', '2017-05-01' ), ( '1', '2017-05-02' ), ( '1', '2017-05-03' ), ( '1', '2017-05-04' ), ( '1', '2017-05-05' ),
( '2', '2017-05-01' ), ( '2', '2017-05-02' ), ( '2', '2017-05-03' ), ( '2', '2017-05-04' ), ( '2', '2017-05-05' )

;WITH d AS (
    SELECT CAST( '05/01/2017' AS DATETIME ) AS date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date + 2
    FROM d
    WHERE date < '2018-07-31'
)
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT LocID, d.date
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT LocID FROM #temp ) AS a
    CROSS JOIN d
OPTION( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

Comment: At first didn't understand your query because format. Is very similar to mine. But two things. **A)** you dont need the `GROUP BY` **B)** You need to return only the `NULL` values from the `LEFT JOIN` to show what dates doesnt have any entry.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - well format liking is subjective - I don't like yours, not enough indentation for my liking. Re **A**: I used `Group By` as the original poster had it in his query to remove duplicates which are important because of **B**. Re **B**: I did not include `WHERE` clause so that OP can compare outputs. Based on the question I assumed he has enough skills to figure this out himself.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing your format, just the fact I didn't understand at first ;)

Comment: Any recommendation for a larger dataset? I'm at 6 minutes and counting for the query...

Comment: @MattP - I have added a second solution. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Alex and @JuanCarlosOropeza. I used a combination of your solutions here and it appears to be working as intended now (and is returning results within ~14 seconds, for 45k rows). I appreciate your help!

Comment: @MattP - on behalf of myself and JuanCarlosOropeza -  you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Your first step was good, you create a list of all dates, but you also need a list of all locations. Then you create a cross join to have all combinations and then you perform the `left join` to find out what is missing.

```
;with allDates(date) as (
  select cast('05/01/2017' as datetime)
  union all
  select date+1
  from d
  where date < '07/31/2017'
 ), allLocations as (
  SELECT DISTINCT loc_id
  FROM @temp
 ), allCombinations as ( 
  SELECT date, loc_id
  FROM allDates
  CROSS JOIN allLocations
 )
SELECT AC.loc_id, AC.date
FROM allCombinations AC
LEFT JOIN @temp t 
  ON AC.date = t.CDate
 AND AC.loc_id = t.loc_id
WHERE t.loc_id IS NULL   -- didnt find a match on @temp
```

Comment: Note you dont need the multiple CTE, you can use a more direct query as @Alex answer, But I want to separate each step so is easy to understand what need to be done.

Comment: Why do you match `AC.loc_id` to `t.CDate` on the join?

Comment: How large the dataset? You can create a temporal table for the `allLocations` create a composite index for `(loc_id, date)` and query should be very fast